# How to add new account in Quickbooks

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Below is the code I am using to try to add a new account to QuickBooks online. I am getting a (400) Bad Request. Can anyone help me with this.

```
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest =
        WebRequest.Create("https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/xxxxxxxxxxx/account")
        as HttpWebRequest;

        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", GetDevDefinedOAuthHeader(httpWebRequest, ConsumerKeyQb, ConsumerSecQb, AccessKey, AccessSec));
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/xml";

        string json = "{\"AccountType\":\"Accounts Receivable\",\"Name\":\"MySampleAccount\"}";

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

        httpWebRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

        using (Stream putStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            putStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = null;
        try
        {
            httpWebResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //return null;
            var x = "Stop";
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

400 response suggests that your API request payload is not correct.

You can try this call using IPP provided .net devkit.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0150_ipp_.net_devkit_3.0/0002_synchronous_calls/0001_data_service_apis

Using Dev-defined lib( sample call ) -
https://gist.github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/0913b4c224de758fde0a

Thanks